# Why can't I up vote/downvote some comments on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Usually on YouTube there are top comments that you can vote, and comments under these that can't be voted up or down.

For example I go on this link while I'm connected to YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSfDzuTLhPU

I see the thumbs up / down for the first 40 comments then the 41st and below have no thumbs up/down anymore.

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Can you link to an example or provide a screenshot? Are you logged in? Do you simply not see the up/down thumbs? On the few videos I've checked I seem to be able to up/down vote _all_ comments.

Comment: totally right, I edited my question and gave a sample link and screenshot

Comment: Do they all appear to be older than 2 years ago?

Comment: I think the further I scroll the older they are, yes. Would that be the reason? I can comment or upvote on very old content on Facebook, stack exchange, vimeo and thousands of other websites with less developing budget than youtube, so why have that limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably due to the [comment system overhaul](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/nov/07/youtube-comments-trolls-moderation-google) that happened around the [end of September 2013](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2013/09/youtube-new-comments.html).

An [NBC News article](http://www.nbcnews.com/technology/want-comment-youtube-videos-now-you-need-google-8C11556258) mentions this:

> The new comment system is in effect now, and you can check it out at any YouTube video. The old comments are still visible, but are trapped in stasis: You can't reply to or rate them. A YouTube representative told NBC News in an email that the the team is "looking into" adding replies or ranking to the old comments, but there's no guarantee.

So with that you'll note that any comment left before the end of 2013 will mostly likely no longer be something you can vote up or down on.

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you very much! It's quite insane that they can't solve it with all the $ they have, it looks kind of like a bug/irregularity.